# Property binding for element with contenteditable="true"

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Property binding is working fine if I have an input in my template

```dart
<div id="textAreaDiv"><input type="text" value={{item.mainText}}></div>
```

but I would like to have an editable div

```dart
<div id="textAreaDiv" contenteditable="true">{{item.mainText}}</div>
```

Is that possible? Can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not to be supported. You should file a bug/feature request.
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list

Comment: Actually, following that link, I found an existing [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13048) which I voted up. Thank you.

Comment: I searched but missed it because it doesn't contain 'Polymer' but I'm sure it's about Poylmer. I starred too.